# GRUB2 doesn't show up in boot options

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

I've tried to install Ubuntu 20.10 (as my GPU is not compatible with 20.04 LTS) as a dual boot on my SSD. I've done the partitioning and separated explicitly the efi from the ext4 partition, I've tried also not doing so but I had same results. Everything seems to go well during the installation, I can even tell that everything is installed correctly because when I boot with the live usb key it recognizes that Ubuntu is installed.

The thing is, I can't launch Ubuntu as it is not in the boot options of my UEFI (asus). I have the following tree structure in my boot options:

```
EFI
-Microsoft
  -- [...]
-Boot
  --bootx64.efi
  --mmx64.efi
  --fb64.efi
-ubuntu
```

When I select the ubuntu folder I get an error message saying 'Invalid File Name'. When I boot first each efi in the boot folder, nothing happens and it ends up booting windows instead (which is at the bottom of the priority list). I've also deactivated fast boot and secure boot.

Now I've tried to solve the problem using boot-repair but it didn't change anything. The summary of boot repair is in the following link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gfKFTMDpM2/. What is said explicitly is that I should boot first /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi which is not one of my options as I can't access ubuntu in the UEFI.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You seem to have drive issues that need to be resolved first. Have you updated UEFI to latest available from Asus. What model Asus? Also update SSD firmware if not latest. Make sure Windows fast start up is off. "The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device." Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` https://askubuntu.com/questions/446991/gparted-claims-whole-hard-drive-is-unallocated-and-gives-warning-about-gpt-table Its really boot shimx64.efi, but your UEFI is not being updated? Perhaps fast start up is locking it.

Comment: I've answered my own post as I managed to solve the issue. Thank you for putting me on the lead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed when typing `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` that `nvme0n1` seemed to not be recognized, which made me figure out that there were a partitioning issue, so I launched GParted.

It told me something was wrong and that I had 5Mo that were not used. Before I did not go through with it because I thought 5Mo was not worth the risk of messing with partition but this time I figured I could give it a try and clicked repair. After that `sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1` command worked and I also launched boot-repair to make sure everything was right. Now everything is working as intended.