# The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device

Tags: partitioning

I had my docker server (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) installed on an old 32GB SSD with two 4.0TB HDDs as data storage. but as i added more docker images soon ran out of space on the tiny ssd. So I had an old SAMSUNG MZNLN256, still not huge but should hold enough for what i need at the moment. I have retried installing ubuntu server several times on it, reformating. but i get an error saying that the GPT partition table is not at the end of the device. the drive was previosley formatted for windows, don't know if that makes any difference? The machine boots ok and seems to work just fine, but i dont really want waste time installing everything until i resolve this problem, just in case. fdisk -l gives the following :-

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZNLN256
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7CF02A77-E414-4F9D-82CC-D23CFA188382

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/sda2  2203648   6397951   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  6397952 500115455 493717504 235.4G Linux filesystem
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device.
```

Comment: You should try the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/446991/590937).

Comment: Also see: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802